# Detect if array function was called as legacy array (ctrl+shift+enter) or as dynamic array (enter)?

Tags: c#, user-defined-functions, excel-dna

```
[ExcelFunction(Description = "Check if function was called as dynamic array or not")]
public static bool IsDynamicArray()
{
    //What goes in here?
}
```

I'd like to know the answer to this because the function I'm using does quite a large DB lookup, and so if it is called as a legacy array, regardless of how many items are retrieved from the DB, it will only display the number of cells selected.

Therefore, I want to know if the array function was called as a legacy array so I can save doing such a large DB lookup, and only return the number of items needed to fill the selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

A function is not ‘called as a dynamic array or not'.

How the array result will be used depends on whether the version of Excel supports the Dynamic Arrays feature.

If Excel *does* support the Dynamic Arrays feature, the function might be called from a simple formula, or from a CSE formuala.
The calling formula might also apply the Implicit intersection @-operator, and only look at one of the values.
Or the formula might be processing the array result using functions like `SORT` or `FILTER`, and then using the results further from there.
The final result might depend on the whole array, even though it only goes into a single cell.
Or (more normally) it might spill to the correct-size region of the sheet.
And the calling region's formula might be a CSE array formula, so the below applies to this version too.

If Excel *does not* support the Dynamic Arrays feature, the function might be called from a single cell, or as a ‘Ctrl+Shift+Enter’ (CSE) formula from a region of the sheet.
If it is a CSE formula, the calling region might be larger, smaller or the right size for the array.

You can disambiguate some of these cases.
You can check whether the version of Excel supports Dynamic Arrays with code like this:

```
    public static class UtilityFunctions
    {
        static bool? _supportsDynamicArrays;
        [ExcelFunction(IsHidden = true)]
        public static bool dnaSupportsDynamicArrays()
        {
            if (!_supportsDynamicArrays.HasValue)
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = XlCall.Excel(614, new object[] { 1 }, new object[] { true });
                    _supportsDynamicArrays = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    _supportsDynamicArrays = false;
                }
            }
            return _supportsDynamicArrays.Value;
        }
    }
```

If Excel does not support Dynamic Arrays, you can get some caller information like this:

```
            var caller = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfCaller) as ExcelReference;
```

Not if `caller == null`, the function is not called from a worksheet.
Otherwise you can examine `caller.RowFirst / RowLast / ColumnFirst / ColumnLast` to determine the calling region’s size.

There are also ways to get the calling formula from the calling range, but then you might still need to parse the formula to figure out what is going on.

Comment: So basically... the answer is No, I can't detect if the function is called from a simple formula, or a CSE formula?

Comment: With pre-Dynamic Arrays versions of Excel, at least you can get the calling range. That's sometimes enough.